# How to add multiple Documents in a zip file in iOS?

Tags: ios, zip

I want make a `zip` file containing multiple documents, documents are taken from my Document Directory.

```
BOOL isDir=NO;

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *subpaths;
for(int i=0; i<[arrdocument count]; i++)
{
    NSString *toCompress = [arrdocument objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *pathToCompress = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:toCompress];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToCompress isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
        subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:pathToCompress];
    } else if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToCompress]) {
        subpaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pathToCompress];
    }

    NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myZipFileName2.zip"];

    ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    [za CreateZipFile2:zipFilePath];

    if (isDir) {
        for(NSString *path in subpaths){
            NSString *fullPath = [pathToCompress stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                [za addFileToZip:fullPath newname:path];
            }
        }
    } else {
        [za addFileToZip:pathToCompress newname:toCompress];
    }
}
```

But when I look at the `zip` file it shows only one document inside the zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you recreate the zip file in each loop iteration. You should instead move the creation of the zip file out of the loop or just specify appending when you create the zip file like this:

```
[za CreateZipFile2:zipFilePath append:YES];
```

Comment: By the way, you should also call CloseZipFile2 when you are finished with the file. In your case, you have to do it after adding the file, before the end of the loop.

Comment: sir there is no option of append in ZipArchive.

Comment: I have "arrdocument", array of files that i want to add into zip File.
suggest if you have the another way to do it.

Comment: What version of ZipArchive are you using? The latest version of [this ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive) has an append parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *zipFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"compressed.zip"];
ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
BOOL result = [zip CreateZipFile2:zipFile];
if(result){
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *allFiles = arrdocument;
    for(int index = 0; index<allFiles.count; index++){
        id singleFileName = [allFiles  objectAtIndex:index];
        NSString *singleFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:singleFileName];
        [zip addFileToZip:singleFilePath newname:singleFileName];
    }
    [zip CloseZipFile2];
}else{
    [self showErrorMessage:@"Unable to to create zip file. Please try again later"  withTitle:@"Error"];
}
```